# How to select specific radio button and get its value in ListView.builder Flutter

Tags: flutter, radio-button, flutter-sliver

I would like to create a list of data that is called JSON with radio button. However, **when I select any of the radio buttons it is selecting each and every radio button rather than selecting one.** And, **how can I get the selected radio button's value when I click on the button**?

I am new to flutter. Is it any solution can solve these type of problems?

Here is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            height: 270,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (context, i) {
                      return Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                              width: 450,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, left: 8.0, top: 10.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xffededed)),
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: <Widget> [
                                  Text(modelOptions[i].optionName.toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      color: Colors.amber,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border:
                                    Border.all(color: const Color(0xffededed)),
                              ),
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemCount: modelOptions[i].modelOptionValues.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, j) {
                                    return
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Radio(
                                            groupValue: selectedRadio,
                                            value: modelOptions[i].modelOptionValues[j].optionValueID,
                                            activeColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                                            onChanged:(value) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                value = modelOptions[i].modelOptionValues[j].optionValueID.toString();
                                                selectedRadio = value;
                                                print("check radio: ${selectedRadio}");
                                                showToastMessage('${selectedRadio} is selected');  //get the selected radio button's value.
                                              });
                                            }),
                                              });
                                            }),
                                        Text(
                                          modelOptions[i].modelOptionValues[j].valueName,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16,
                                        ),),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  }))
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                    childCount: modelOptions.length,
                  ),
                ),
                
              ],
            )),
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Comment: You're thinking in an imperative fashion instead of a declarative one. You should already know the value and be applying that data to the radio button.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are talking about. Is it I did wrong for my concept?

Comment: You shouldn't be asking anything for it's value, you should know the value and be applying that value to the thing.

Comment: but now when I click on one button, it selects all.

Comment: because you have once source of data `_isSelected` which is a bool. so they're all going to be set to that. you need a `List<bool>`. and update the index with the value.

Comment: I'll answer the question.

Comment: I think you can see the error now though right? you already have a collection of models. you need to store the value there.

Comment: I am not quite sure it is something like this? I had added the id for each choice for the value in the Radio. But, it will straight away show all buttons is selected even I didn't choose anything.

Comment: The code you posted is very complex and has a lot of dependencies for me to decipher what's happening.

Comment: What is see is this ```                                        Checkbox(
                                            checkColor: Colors.white,
                                            value: _isChecked,
                                            onChanged: (value) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                _isChecked = true;
                                              });
                                            }),```
which is setting one value and applying one value to ALL Checkboxes

Comment: I am sorry to make you feel confused, but my question is on the Radio button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238159/discussion-between-nico-spencer-and-smile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                                        Radio(
                                            groupValue: selectedRadio,
                                            activeColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                                            onChanged: (val) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                selectedRadio = val;
                                                showToastMessage(
                                                    "' the value ?? ' is selected"); //get the selected radio button's value.
                                              });
                                            }),
```

You're using one source of truth for the Radio's value `selectedRadio`. You should be updating the value for an index. Furthermore you're passing the value to the `groupValue` parameter instead of the `value` parameter. `groupValue` is how you... toggle the group.